# How do I solve getting ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT exception using Google/YouTube API?

Tags: java, spring, youtube-data-api

I am creating a website using Spring Boot 2.7.9 (Spring 5) that is making calls to the YouTube API (via an Open Feign interface). Right now, I'm just trying to successfully call getRatings, using the scope below, but am getting the exception below. I already created users before adding this scope.

One solution seems to be "revoke the users access and then authorize your application again" which I assume means to go to "https://console.cloud.google.com/apis" but I could not find where on there to do that.

Is there something else I need to do, like specify the scopes during user authentication on my app? Add a header to the request to YouTube?

I'm not sure what other info you need in order to help me solve this, so please let me know that.

```
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Insufficient Permission",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
            }
        ],
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
                "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
                "domain": "googleapis.com",
                "metadata": {
                    "service": "youtube.googleapis.com",
                    "method": "youtube.api.v3.V3DataVideoRatingService.List"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

An example access token looks like this

```
ya29.a0AfB_byAc7...
```

My Open Feign call to Google looks like this:

```
@FeignClient(value = "youTubeService", url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3")
public interface FeignYouTubeService
{
  @GetMapping("/videos/getRating")
  YouTubeRatingResponse getVideoRating(//
    @RequestHeader(name = "Authorization")
    String accessToken,
    @RequestParam("id")
    String videoId, //
    @RequestParam("key")
    String key);
```

Here I'm showing that my app has that scope.

[image]

When I set this up in Postman, it works. So what's the difference? What in my Spring Security could be different?